# The Dreaded Type Mismatch for Two Concatenated Strings -- Why?

Tags: excel, vba

This code works:

```
Dim tline1 As Variant
tline1 = EIRPCases.Range(EIRPCases.Cells(CaseStart + 1 + (i - 1) * CaseRowNum, 4),EIRPCases.Cells(32 + (i - 1) * CaseRowNum, 4)).Value
[EB_WGType].Value = tline1
```

That is, it copies the string of tline1 into the cell named EB_WGType

But the following returns the Type mismatch error:

```
Dim tline1 As Variant, tline2 As Variant
tline1 = EIRPCases.Range(EIRPCases.Cells(CaseStart + 1 + (i - 1) * CaseRowNum, 4),EIRPCases.Cells(32 + (i - 1) * CaseRowNum, 4)).Value
tline2 = EIRPCases.Range(EIRPCases.Cells(CaseStart + 1 + (i - 1) * CaseRowNum, 5),EIRPCases.Cells(32 + (i - 1) * CaseRowNum, 5)).Value
[EB_WGType].Value = tline1 & tline2
```

I just want to concatenate the tline1 and tline2 strings and copy them into the named cell EB_WGType. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

With `tline1` and `tline2` defined as `Variant`s that receive their values from ranges that most likely span multiple cells, they are actually arrays.  The `&` operator doesn't know how to concatenate them.

You could try a `For...Next` loop to manually build a string representation of `tline1` and `tline2` and then concatenate those.  E.g.

```
Dim tline1 As Variant, tline2 As Variant, c As Variant
Dim sTmptline1 As String, sTmptline2 As String

tline1 = EIRPCases.Range(EIRPCases...
tline2 = EIRPCases.Range(EIRPCases...

For Each c In tline1
    sTmptline1 = sTmptline1 & CStr(c)
Next
For Each c In tline2
    sTmptline2 = sTmptline1 & CStr(c)
Next
[EB_WGType].Value = sTmptline1 & sTmptline2
```

However, as you're iterating through the arrays building the string, you might as well just consume both arrays into sTmptline. E.g.

```
Dim tline1 As Variant, tline2 As Variant, c As Variant
Dim sTmptline As String

tline1 = EIRPCases.Range(EIRPCases...
tline2 = EIRPCases.Range(EIRPCases...

For Each c In tline1
    sTmptline = sTmptline & CStr(c)
Next
For Each c In tline2
    sTmptline = sTmptline & CStr(c)
Next
[EB_WGType].Value = sTmptline
```

Note that arrays created directly from ranges are two-dimensional arrays (even if they only consist of data from one row or one column) so you can't use the `Join` function without first converting them to one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Steve, your code sort of worked. In the worksheet that is being referenced, the 1st string (tline1) is "WG", and the second string (tline2) is "AL". The desired output is WGAL. However, your code produces this output: WGWGWGWGWGWGWGWGALALALALALALALAL. It copies the 1st string 8 times, then concatenates that to the 2nd string which is also copied 8 times. Any idea why?

Comment: Steve, I modified your code successfully and added it to the bottom of your answer. Thanks for your help.